# Cost model for different curve models

Tags: elliptic-curves, finite-field

Is there a cost model for each curve model and their conversions?

For example:

Take the curve models: Projective, Completed, Extended, Affine.

Is there a table which shows how many multiplications, additions and divisions it costs to do point addition and point doubling for example?

Maybe a guide on when to choose each curve model over the other and or when the conversion to another model is worth it in terms of cost. I do not have any references, however I remember some programs always converting back to either a completed point or an extended point.

Answer (score 1):

The [Explicit Formulas Database, EFD](https://hyperelliptic.org/EFD/) catalogs a variety of curve forms, coordinate systems, and algorithms for arithmetic operations, along with operation counts and references to the literature.